# objective-c: proper way to generate a lot of instances of a certain class without creating a memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

I'm making a simple SpriteKit game. It has one randomly generated world made up of lines. These lines are represented by the NHRLineNode class. I generate these lines all at once in the beginning of the level with two for loops, one for each side of the screen. This works fine. In addition to the main gameplay scene of the game, there is a "game over" screen that displays between plays and shows your score etc and a main menu scene. The problem comes when I play the game, die, see the game over screen, and play again. Looking at the memory usage in Xcode, it seems like the memory usage goes up when I first start the game from the menu scene, stays steady throughout the gameplay, and then jumps 6-10 MB when I die. This memory is never regained and the app uses more and more memory every time I play. I think this is because my for loops that generate the platforms are just creating a new instance of the NHRLineNode class, positioning it correctly, and then doing it again. Is this what is causing my memory issues? Or is it more likely something on the game over scene?

Relevant snippets:

The for loops that generate the platforms:

```
    int previousXVal1 = -10;
    int previousYVal1 = 425;
    int newXPosition = 0;
    //How many do you want?

    int numToGen = 100;
    for(int i = 1; i<=numToGen; i++) {



        NHRLineNode *lineGen = [NHRLineNode initAtPosition:CGPointMake(previousXVal1 + arc4random_uniform(85), previousYVal1 - 75)];
        [worldNode addChild:lineGen];
        if(lineGen.position.x > 390) {
            newXPosition = lineGen.position.x - 100; //That should bring it onscreen!
            lineGen.position = CGPointMake(newXPosition, lineGen.position.y); //Make the new position

        } else if (lineGen.position.x < 100) {
            newXPosition = lineGen.position.x + 100; //That will bring it onscreen!!
            lineGen.position = CGPointMake(newXPosition, lineGen.position.y);
                        }
        previousXVal1 = lineGen.position.x;
        previousYVal1 = lineGen.position.y;


    }
    //This creates the lines on the right side (performing the inverse calculation on the x pos
    //int numToGen = 10;

    int previousXVal2 = 350;
    int previousYVal2 = 525;
    for(int i = 1; i<=numToGen; i++) {


        NHRLineNode *lineGen = [NHRLineNode initAtPosition:CGPointMake(previousXVal2 - arc4random_uniform(85), previousYVal2 - 75)];
        [worldNode addChild:lineGen];
        if(lineGen.position.x > 390) { //It is partially off-screeb=n
            newXPosition = lineGen.position.x - 100; //That should bring it onscreen!
            lineGen.position = CGPointMake(newXPosition, lineGen.position.y); //Make the new position
        } else if (lineGen.position.x < 100) { //It is partially off-screen
            newXPosition = lineGen.position.x + 100; //That will bring it onscreen!!
            lineGen.position = CGPointMake(newXPosition, lineGen.position.y);
        }

        previousXVal2 = lineGen.position.x;
        previousYVal2 = lineGen.position.y;



    }
```

The initAtPosition method of NHRLineNode:

```
+(id)initAtPosition:(CGPoint)point {
//This is all the properties of one of the lines in the level
SKSpriteNode *theLine = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"newLine"];
//The physics body is slightly smaller than the image itself -- why idk
theLine.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(75,5)];
//It is not affected by gravity
theLine.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
//Its position is the point given us when the function was called
theLine.position = point;
//Return it for further positioning by the generator
return theLine;
}
```

Entire implementation of GameOverScene: http://pastebin.com/wUpguueb

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, is this ARC or manual reference counting?

Comment: Note that this is wrong: `[NHRLineNode initAtPosition:...`.  You should be doing `[[NHRLineNode alloc] initAtPosition:...`, or else call your method something that doesn't begin with `init`.

Comment: Also, if you want to find out what's leaking, run the Leaks instrument and check out what it points you to.

Comment: It's ARC. Instruments only shows 64 bytes leaking every once in a while, caused by PhysicsKit. I will change the allocation of NHRLineNode when I have time later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you have ARC on your side, sometimes you need to give it "incentive" to free objects, especially when creating many in a loop. Really, this simply has to do with providing scope, so ARC understands that it may release allocated instances.

Try wrapping the *bodies* of your for loops (i.e. not around the entire for loops), with `@autoreleasepool { …}` - i.e., as if that @autoreleasepool block is the only statement for the for loop.

Let is know if it helps! I commonly have to do this when iteratively importing data to Core Data.

Comment: @autoreleasepool and changing the class method of NHRLineNode to createAtPosition (per the suggestion above) has some effect, but not much. RAM usage is now increasing by 2-4 MB every game and never goes down.

Comment: I rewrote the generator and made some other improvements, and now the problem is virtually nonexistent. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why does he need to use an autorelease pool at all? Under ARC, all nodes should be deallocated once removed from their parent node (provided it's the only strong reference). Am I missing something?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Assuming one never creates a new autoreleasepool, the first one created (usually wrapping the call to the app instance in an xcode template-created main.m) will certainly drain and deallocate instances at some point in the future. However, within a function, a loop can easily create many instances unwittingly. Because they are all autoreleased by ARC, they hang around until that main pool drains -- this is (most likely) not before that function exits. By creating another autoreleasepool for the loop's body, you guarantee it's drained every loop iteration.

Comment: @greymouser I know, especially when a large loop creates lots of instances. But it's not like they're going to leak without the pool; at most, they'll be deallocated relatively late, and incur in memory pressure, right?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Yes, at no point is it technically a leak, since no references to the allocated instances are getting lost. But also: that's exactly it -- the memory pressure from not giving ARC some hints that it may release objects when they are done with can incur so much memory pressure that unintended side-effects occur, e.g. application crash. The point is, if you don't see a problem with a given loop, don't use @autoreleasepool{}; if you do, use it make sure those instances are released every iteration. For further points on this, read the Apple Transitioning to Arc guide which covers it.